# Given that $\frac{a}{1-x}+\frac{b}{1+2x}\approx-3+12x$ for small values of $x$, find the value of $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> Given that $\frac{a}{1-x}+\frac{b}{1+2x}\approx-3+12x$ for small values of $x$, find the value of $a$ and $b$.

This question is very hard i am on the chapter of Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ for values of n that are not positive integers i know how to solve these questions but have no idea how to solve this type of question when involves 2 unknown variables.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}\approx 1 + x$, apply this to your problem.

Comment: @Joshua Wang where did you get this from?

Comment: Binomial approximation of $(1-x)^{-1}$.

Comment: Generally, $(1 + x)^{n}\approx 1 + nx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+y}\approx 1 - y$ for small $y$, we wish to find $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$\frac{a}{1-x} + \frac{b}{1 + 2x} \approx 12x - 3$$

$$a(1 + x) + b(1 - 2x)= 12x - 3$$

$$(a - 2b)x + (a + b)= 12x - 3$$

Now, to make all of the terms match we have the system of linear equations:

$$\begin{cases}a - 2b = 12\\a + b = -3\end{cases}$$

Solving, we get $\boxed{(a, b) = (2, -5).}$

Comment: 1/1+y≈1−y this is a general formula like when would i use it?

Comment: @Hiran It is coming from the fact that $$
\frac{1}{{1 + y}} = 1 - y + y^2  - y^3  + y^4  -  \cdots 
$$ for $|y|<1$. Look up "geometric series".

Comment: owwww i see and when do i know when to use it?

Comment: "When do I know when to use it?" Well, you said you're in the chapter on binomial expansions...

Answer (score 0):

As a (fill the gap) re the other responses:

$(1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) = 1-x^{(n+1)} \approx 1$, for small values of $x$.  In fact, when $|x| < 1$, the infinite series $(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}.$

Further, for small values of $x$, it is reasonable to discard **all but the first two terms** of $(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots).$

This implies that for small values of $x$, $\frac{1}{1-x}$ can be approximated by $(1 + x).$

Similarly, $(1 + 2y)\times [1 - 2y + 4y^2 - 8y^3 + \cdots - \cdots + (-1)^n (2y)^n] = 1 + [-2y]^{(n+1)}.$

Therefore, for $|y| < \frac{1}{2}$, the infinite series 
$[1 - 2y + 4y^2 - 8y^3 + \cdots - \cdots ]$ converges to $\frac{1}{1 + 2y}$.

Thus, similar to the analysis in the first part of this answer, for small values of $y,~ \frac{1}{1 + 2y}$ may be approximated by $(1 - 2y).$

---

The above analysis begs the question: how do you know what approximations to take.

**Answer**
Look at the original problem.
Since the RHS is a first degree polynomial, a **blind guess** is that you want to find first degree polynomials to approximate the LHS, for small values of $x$.

Unfortunately, this blind guess requires the abstract vision that such a LHS approximation will result in two (**solvable**) linear equations in two unknowns for the variables $a,b.$

It is reasonable to surmise that the premise that $x$ is a small value is *authorizing* polynomial approximations to the fractions.  It is then reasonable to question what degree polynomials should be used for the LHS approximations.

You are then supposed to question as follows: how could the LHS polynomial approximations be of degree higher than $1$, and still be equivalent to the RHS polynomial?